Arduino ESP8266 (arduino-esp8266) documentation for core_esp8266_waveform.h
Intro
I have found by chance the following header file in Arduino core library for ESP8266:
core_esp8266_waveform.h
That defines interesting functions like startWaveform that should allow for playing (maybe?) an arbitrary waveform using pwm.
I would like to know more about this library that seems interesting.
What I have tried
I have looked for documentation but I have found only these:
https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.1/
https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
These are documentation of the Arduino ESP8266 platform but there is no trace of the waveform library.
Source files are in the following path:
[framework-arduinoespressif8266 home path]/cores/esp8266
And interesting files are:
core_esp8266_waveform.h
core_esp8266_waveform_phase.cpp
Final question
Beyond trial and error and self studying what the source does (that I will do as a last resort), is there some documentation I was not able to find?

You might want to try asking in [arduino.se].
